Dynamic environment (URL) in IONIC Angular
As the title says, I am looking for a way to use only one environment.prod.ts file where the environment URL can be set from the login screen in my Ionic app, but I can't find a way to make it dynamic. I am doing the following:
environment.prod.ts
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  url: ''
};


Set value:
this.url = (await this.storage.get('urlUser')) || null;
environment.url = this.url;

But this way it does not work, since the value I send is not saved and remains blank when I am going to use it.
I tried this way, but just the service I use runs first, so the URL is empty.
  URL = ''

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private userService: UserService,
    private fileOpener: FileOpener,
    private storage: Storage
  ) {
    this.geturl()
  }

  async geturl() {
    this.URL = (await this.storage.get('urlUser')) || null;
  }

So I don't know if there is a global way to have the URL before to not have problems with synchronous services from the environment.prod.ts file.
This is what I put in the *.service.ts before the class
const URL = environment.url;

Version
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.2",
    "@ionic/angular": "^6.1.4",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.1.1",
    "@ionic/storage": "^3.0.6",
    "@ionic/storage-angular": "^3.0.6",

Regards.

The reason your URL is empty cause your calling this.geturl() in the constructor. The storage needs lil time to get the value out. You need to place this in a lifecyclehook -- https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks. Also where are you placing this code? This should be place within the app.component.ts file.
